# How can I create an inherited object in the admin from an existing base model instance?

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I have the following

```
class Employee(User):
    emplorateID=models.OneToOneField(Code) 
    business=models.ForeignKey(Business)
```

but I have existing Users that I'd like to select in the `EmployeeAdmin` and enter the additional field data for. I don't see how I would customize the `ModelAdmin` to handle creating a new `Employee` from an existing `User` (effectively a new row in the `Employee` table for referencing the existing `User` entry)

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance isn't what you want in this case; you just need another model with a `OneToOneField` pointing back.

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='employee')
    emplorateID = models.OneToOneField(Code)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
```

It should JustWork™.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the form answer, but here is the code answer:

```
employee = Employee(user_ptr=existing_user,
                    emplorateID=something,
                    business=somebusiness)
employee.save_base(raw=True)
```